# How to exclude terms in nested composite aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using composite aggregation on nested fields in elasticsearch but I want to exclude some terms from the result.

This aggregation is working:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "geo": {
    "communication": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "geo"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "table": {
          "composite": {
            "size": 1000,
            "sources": [
              {"stk1": {"terms": {"field": "geo.src"}}},
              {"stk2": {"terms": {"field": "geo.dest"}}}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to exclude some terms from stk2,

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "geo": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "geo"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "table": {
          "composite": {
            "size": 1000,
            "sources": [
              {"stk1": {"terms": {"field": "geo.src"}}},
              {"stk2": {"terms": {"field": "geo.dest", "exclude":"cancel"}}}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query is not working.

UPDATE 1: The result should omit only the array elements and not the entire document containing "cancel".

I am using elastic v6.7

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a query to exclude those documents:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "geo": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "geo"
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "prefix": {
              "geo.dest": "cancel"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "table": {
          "composite": {
            "size": 10,
            "sources": [
              {
                "stk1": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "geo.src"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "stk2": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "geo.dest"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @val for the prompt reply. I am actually looking to omit only the elements of the array which contains "cancel" and not the entire document. Can you please re-check?

Comment: You missed "path" in nested. I tested it but now it is giving this error:- **[composite] aggregation cannot be used with a parent aggregation of type: [FilterAggregatorFactory]**

Comment: You're absolutely right, my bad. A [pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/38863) will remedy to this. Not sure when the fix will be released, though.

Comment: any workaround you would suggest? BTW, thank you for the support! very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you need to use `nested` types? Can you show a sample document?

Comment: Yes absolutely. without nested the composite aggregation would give false results. You can take any basic mapping like {a:"random text", b:[{ c:"random text", d: "random text"},{ c: "random text", d:"random text"}]}

Comment: Yes, I know, but what I'm saying is why do you need to use the nested type in your document mapping? I'm curious why `geo` needs to be an array in the first place.

Comment: so that the objects does not get flattened by elastic search. I have to group the results based on the combinations of 'c' and 'd' (which are actually present in the documents). Now, if I dont use nested, the results are basically cross product of the elements which also include 'c' 'c' and 'd' 'd'. Please see this like an airline system, which can have a direct flight (1 element in the array), or a flight with multiple stops.