# Is it possible to make elasticsearch aggregations faster when I only want the top 10 buckets?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I understand elasticsearch aggregation queries take a long time to execute by nature, especially on high cardinality fields. In our use case, we only need to bring back the first x buckets sorted alphabetically. Considering we only need to bring back 10 buckets, is there a way to make our query faster? Is there a way to get Elasticsearch to look at only the first 10 buckets in each shard and compare those only?

Here is my query...

```
{
    "size": "600",
    "timeout": "60s",
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_all": {
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "firstname": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "firstname.keyword",
                "size": 10,
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                "order": {
                    "_key": "asc"
                },
                "include": ".*.*",
                "exclude": ""
            }
        }
}
}
```

I think I am on to something using a composite aggregation instead. Like this...

```
"home_address1": {
    "composite": {
        "size": 10,
        "sources": [
            {
                "home_address1": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "home_address1.keyword",
                        "order": "asc"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Testing in Postman shows that this request takes way faster. Is this expected? If so, awesome. How can I add the include, exclude attributes to the composite query? For example, sometimes I only want to include buckets whose value matches "A.*"

If this query should not be any faster, then why does it appear so?

Comment: What's your query? What's your mapping? Example entries?

Answer (score 0):

Composite terms aggs unfortunately don't support `include`, `exclude` and many other standard terms aggs' parameters so you've got 2 options:

1. Filter out the docs that don't match your prefix from within the query, like [@Val pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059780/how-to-exclude-terms-in-nested-composite-aggregation).

or

2. use a script to do the filtering for you. This should be your last resort though -- scripts are pretty much guaranteed to run more slowly than standard query filters.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "home_address1": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 10,
        "sources": [
          {
            "home_address1": {
              "terms": {
                "order": "asc",
                "script": {
                  "source": """
                    def val = doc['home_address1.keyword'].value;
                    if (val == null) { return null; }

                    if (val.indexOf('A.') === 0) {
                      return val;
                    }

                    return null;
                  """,
                  "lang": "painless"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

BTW your original `terms` agg already seems optimized so it surprises me that the `composite` is faster.

Comment: The composite query is definitely faster. It surprises me as well, but I have no idea why that is the case.

Comment: Neither do I. Found this agg suitability helper https://run.plnkr.co/preview/ck9ixg4pu00093h5zjvz1dur8/ and even it suggests composite for your use case. Anyways, are your agg times reasonable now?

Comment: What is that link, @jzzfs? Looks interesting, but doesn't work.